# Efficient WMS or TMS Loop for Radar data?

Tags: openlayers-2, wms, tilecache, animation

I'm looking for an efficient way to loop radar data from a Tilecache or WMS Server.  Right now, I make an array of layers and increment through them, but this seems inefficient since I end up with a lot of layers for what should be just one layer. I saw this post: https://gis.stackexchange.com/a/20836/7387, however, I'm not sure how to go about implementing what is suggested...

```
          {Destroy Layers} |10|11...19|20| {Start Loading Layers}
|---------------------------------------------------------------------------|
                           ↑
        Timespan           Current Possition
```

Can you do this on a single layer? A simple example to follow would be very helpful. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

Depending on what you need it may be that the new WMS animator from GeoServer could be a solution to your problem. See http://docs.geoserver.org/stable/en/user/tutorials/animreflector.html for more details.

[This blog post](http://geo-solutions.blogspot.co.uk/2011/11/animate-your-maps-with-geoserver.html) gives a longer account and an example.

[image: Animated Map]

Comment: Thanks @iant! I looked into that and its nice, but the server admins are only allowing MapServer at the moment. :-(